# VBScript runtime error '800a0034' - Bad file name or number - When trying to write to server side text file

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I'm trying to simply write to a text file for later use data collected from input elements on various pages. Admittedly I am likely missing the obvious, but of the variations I have tried and even some of the sample code I have found in many examples I always get the same error.

**Code:**

```
<%
  Dim currentDirectoryPath, outFile, objFSO, objTextStream

  Const fsoForWriting = 2

  'Get and assign current directory path
  currentDirectoryPath = Server.MapPath(".")

  'Assign file name to be used
  outFile = "\accdata.txt\"

  Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'Open the text file
  Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(currentDirectoryPath & outFile, fsoForWriting, True)

  'Write new line to text file
  objTextStream.WriteLine "output this as one line of text"

  'Close the file and clean up
  objTextStream.Close
  Set objTextStream = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

**Result:**

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0034'

Bad file name or number

/asp/accounting/datacollect.asp, line 23

(Line 23 of the code is:)

```
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(currentDirectoryPath & outFile, fsoForWriting, True)
```

This is far from being my first language and thus I don't posses a heap load of experience with it so any help or suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: If this is VB.NET then you should be using the .NET `FileStream` class.  If this is classic ASP then fix your tags.

Comment: and why does your file name end in a backslash?

Comment: Hi Mark.. An earlier problem I encountered was: "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' - Permission denied". The solution I found to this was to terminate the file name with a backslash.

Comment: Ah Ha !! Thank you Mark. You alerted me to something I'd thought I'd resolved and hadn't. I found a script that checks if a file exists. Without the extra backslash the file exists but I get the original "Permission denied" error, and with the extra backslash the file is not found. So the extra backslash is being considered as actually part of the file name which gives me the "Bad file name or number" error and the permission error is not relevant. So it looks like I could use help resolving the permission error. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I would guess that your anonymous inet user doesn't have rights to that path.